# How to restore Firefox download progress bar in Unity launcher?

Tags: unity, firefox, launcher, downloads

Firefox used to be better integrated with Unity: when downloading it would show the number of files and a progress bar. This was achieved through the [Unityfox add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/unityfox/), but it no longer works and the development seems to have ceased.

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this in a current version of Firefox (say, version 31 in Ubuntu 14.04)?

Even the newest version of Thunderbird seems to work just fine, displaying the number of unread emails in the launcher, so I imagine there's some way for that functionality to be added back into Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Unityfox Revived add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/unityfox-revived/) is the current successor.